# What is the latest version of Intraweb that Arcana Elite Suite is compatible with?

Tags: delphi, intraweb

The [Arcana Elite Suite](http://code.google.com/p/iwelite/) for Intraweb hasn't been updated since March 2008. Does this mean it won't work with any bundled Intraweb later than Delphi 2007?

Anyone tried it with D2009 or D2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest change is r33 (21 Nov 2009). You need to get this version via SVN.

Comments for this version:
*"Modified a bunch of files to compile using IW10 and D2009
Not fully tested
IMHO For obvious coherence, all string types must be replaced to ansistring
types"*

http://code.google.com/p/iwelite/source/detail?r=33

I did try the Server Manager component but did not succeed to get this up and running. At that time had no interest in the other components.

Gert

Answer (score 1):

Arcana Elite Suite 2.6.7 works perfectly on Intraweb 10.0.23, but on D2007 (not sure about D2009+)